# emulator window was out of view and was recentered (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, emulation, android-virtual-device

i was following a tutorial to install Cordova. Installation was completed successfully without any errors.

I created an android virtual machine, but when i tried to run it, it started showing an error `emulator window was out of view and was recentered` I searched online for this error but was unable to find any suitable solution. AVD runs for a few seconds and then closes automatically.

Here's the screen that runs for a few second

[image]

This is the error screen

[image]

Here's my Virtual Device configuration:

[image]

I also tried changing RAM size from 512 to 256. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04